# distance between two points (x,y) weighted by location (x)

Tags: linear, distance, weights

a new on algebra. I am trying to create an indicator of the distance between two points (x,y) from a (0,1) scale, but I want to create a weight that reduces such distances as the point x is closer to 1 per individual. x contains individual values within a cluster and y is the cluster average. Negative values imply that someone is below the average, and positive values mean that someone is above the average. I tried something like this, but it is not correct because the value in x2 should be smaller than x1. Is there a better way to do it?

$$ x_p = x_1\dfrac{1}{(x_1 - \overline{x})}    $$
I have two clusters with two individuals.

$$ x1 =(0.3,0.7),  \overline{x1}= 0.5, x_p1 = (-0.15, 0.15) \\ 
x2 =(0.5,0.9), \overline{x2}= 0.7 , x_p2 = (-2.5, 2.5)
$$

Comment: It's possible that it might be better to ask on mathematics.stackexchange.  The question doesn't seem to involve anything statistical.  Although you are trying to solve a problem concerning clustering, the question itself doesn't seem like it's about clustering per se.  Perhaps I am misunderstanding, though.  Someone here might answer, but you will draw on a different range of expertise at Math.SE.  (Don't ask on two sites at once, though.  If you move the question to Math.SE, you will need to delete it here.)

Comment: ok, thanks. I will try in the mathematic section in StackExchange.